# maintain scroll postion from one page to the next page

Tags: php, javascript

I want to maintain scroll postion from one page to the next page after clicking the link.

Can some one tell how i can do this?

e.g. I want to click a link in `index.php` and then after opening the next page it should have the same scroll position that was in `index.php`.

Comment: Why?  This seems like it would be incredibly counterintuitive.  I'd probably get aggravated real quick and spend most of my time scrolling back up to the top of the page or just not being on your site altogether.

Answer (score 0):

On window exit, use ajax or localstorage to store the scroll position in a database (or just a file). Then on the new page, retrieve the original scroll position with ajax or localstorage and scroll to that position. I'm not going to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bad idea but you could do it something like this (assuming jQuery and modern browser):

```
$("a").click(function() {
  localStorage["scrollPosition"] = $(window).scrollTop();
});


$(function() {
  $(window).scrollTop(localStorage["scrollPosition"]);
});
```